# GCC cross-compiler can't find header file

Tags: compiling, make, gcc, cross-compilation, toolchain

A host PC with a pre-built cross toolchain for ARM target. I try to build a project from source,  the build process stopped due to an error, when code tried to build pppd-2.4.1 module, here is relevant part of log:

```
... ... ...
if [ -f pppd/Makefile.cyt ]; then \
    make -C pppd -f Makefile.cyt; \
else \
    make -C pppd; \
fi
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/vestjo/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1'
make -C pppd
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/vestjo/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1/pppd'
/opt/emlix/pnx8181/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O2 -pipe -Wall -g -DHAVE_PATHS_H -DIPX_CHANGE -DHAVE_MMAP -I../include '-DDESTDIR="/usr/local"' -DCHAPMS=1 -DMPPE=1 -DHAS_SHADOW -DHAVE_CRYPT_H=1 -DUSE_CRYPT=1 -DHAVE_MULTILINK -DUSE_TDB=1 -DPLUGIN -DMAXOCTETS   -c -o utils.o utils.c
utils.c:79:21: error: cy_conf.h: No such file or directory
<builtin>: recipe for target 'utils.o' failed
make[4]: *** [utils.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/vestjo/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1/pppd'
Makefile.cyt:18: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/vestjo/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1'
/home/vestjo/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/Rules.mk:74: recipe for target '_subdir_pppd' failed
make[2]: *** [_subdir_pppd] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/vestjo/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source'
/home/vestjo/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/Rules.mk:74: recipe for target '_subdir_open_source' failed
make[1]: *** [_subdir_open_source] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vestjo/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router'
Rules.mk:74: recipe for target '_subdir_router' failed
make: *** [_subdir_router] Error 2
```

The compiler can't find header file, 'cy_conf.h'. The header file path: `$(SRCBASE)/include/cy_conf.h`. Project makefiles have complex structure, multi-level recursive makefiles.

- A top-level directory [Makefile](https://pastebin.com/MDSE532f) and [Rules.mk](https://pastebin.com/M3adcWvg) file
- [toolchain.mk](https://pastebin.com/ciXBK6m0) file from the configuration files folder
- [configure](https://pastebin.com/WBHbN7tn) script and [Makefile](https://pastebin.com/JPL3TTRw) for target 'pppd-2.4.1' module
- [Makefile](https://pastebin.com/Z1L0yxf2) for 'pppd' subdirectory (/pppd-2.4.1/pppd)

Project top-most directory contains no configuration file, although some modules in subdirectories have config files inside. Project should be built by executing the Makefile in the main(top-most) directory. It doesn't require run these config files prior build the code. How to make the gcc compiler find the header file?

Edit: same error when run 'make' within `/pppd` directory(down-level folder).

```
pppd$ make
cc -O2 -pipe -Wall -g -DHAVE_PATHS_H -DIPX_CHANGE -DHAVE_MMAP -I../include '-DDESTDIR="/usr/local"' -DCHAPMS=1 -DMPPE=1 -DHAS_SHADOW -DHAVE_CRYPT_H=1 -DUSE_CRYPT=1 -DHAVE_MULTILINK -DUSE_TDB=1 -DPLUGIN -DMAXOCTETS   -c -o utils.o utils.c
utils.c:79:21: fatal error: cy_conf.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cy_conf.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'utils.o' failed
```

Comment: Try to go in the directory pppd/ and run make. The flag 'I../include' should point to the header file. Is this file there?

Comment: Same error when run 'make' within /pppd directory.

Comment: Is cy_conf.h in the sources (run find . -name 'cy_conf' in the top directory of the sources)??

Comment: 'cy_conf.h' file found in two places: `./router/open_source/pkgs/net-snmp-5.7.3/include/net-snmp/cy_conf.h` and `./router/open_source/include/cy_conf.h`,
but **not** in the top directory of the sources, as specified in top Makefile: `export CY_CONF_H := $(SRCBASE)/include/cy_conf.h`. There is no 'include' folder in top dir.

Comment: Ok. Are you using a release tarball of the sources or did you clone a development repository? (Github/Gitlab...)??

Comment: It's tarball of the sources. I can't exclude that this tarball may contain minor errors during preparation of its structure, though. For example there is no  'include' folder in top src dir, although Makefile have reference on it: `export CY_CONF_H := $(SRCBASE)/include/cy_conf.h`

Comment: Ok I'm back home... I looked at the sources releases: https://download.samba.org/pub/ppp/ 2.4.1 is from 2001. Any reason you are using such an old version?

Answer (score 2):

ppp-2.4.1 sources can be downloaded here: [https://download.samba.org/pub/ppp/](https://download.samba.org/pub/ppp/ppp-2.4.1.tar.gz)
the build instructions are classic: first you configure the build by running the configure script at the top of the source directory.

If the configuration does not work, it can be helpful to know that the preprocessor is responsible for finding includes.
 `export CPPFLAGS=-I${SRCBASE}/include` can help before running the configure script

In order to cross compile this package, you have to adapt your compiler at compile time:

```
CC=<name of>-<your>-<tuple here>-gcc make
```

Comment: where should be added this `export CPPFLAGS=-I${SRCBASE}/include`, in project top Makefile or toolchain.mk?

Comment: you should run this before you run the configure script (in the top directory of the sources.

Comment: There is no .configure script in the top directory of sources. Does this export CPPFLAGS shouldn't be specified globally in the top Makefile or toolchain.mk files?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes you have to provide these flags yourself. How do you run the build and configure it?

Comment: I tried run command `export CPPFLAGS=-I${SRCBASE}/include` from the top directory top of the sources. Then 'make', but the same result. I followed build [instructions](https://pastebin.com/NZSuE0zJ) that indicate untar package, $ cd to /src folder, $ make, $ make install.

Comment: There IS a configure script in the top directory of sources: https://download.samba.org/pub/ppp/ppp-2.4.1.tar.gz

Comment: yes, there is `.configure` script in the top dir of pppd-2.4.1 sources.
What I meant, there is no configure script in the _top directory of project (src)_.
I tried run `make clean`, `./configure`, `make` in the pppd-2.4.1 directory, but always got same error
`utils.c:79:21: fatal error: cy_conf.h: No such file or directory`. Possibly, something's wrong with the compiler configuration.